# Install Error : System.IO.PathTooLongException mvvm-light

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, mvvm-light

When trying to install the VSIX template in VS 2010, I am receiving a **Install Error : System.IO.PathTooLongException**.  Once it takes my default extension folder and adds "\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\MVVM Light Toolkit Templates\4.0.23.0\ItemTemplates\Silverlight for Windows Phone\Mvvm\MvvmViewModelLocator.WP7.zip", it is too long to install.  Is there any way to have a shorter path or a way around this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installing Cosmopolitan template.

1. Rename .vsix file to .zip.
2. Open it and there's a file extension.vsixmanifest, open it in Notepad or other editor.
3. Find node `<Name>Some very long name of the extension</Name>` and make it short `<Name>Short name</Name>`
4. Save, close. Rename .zip to .vsix and now it should install without an error.